# How to Run a DataBricks Notebook From Another Notebook with "different cluster"

Tags: databricks

In Databricks I understand that a notebook can be executed from another notebook but the notebook will run in the current cluster by default.

For eg: I have notebook1 running on cluster1 and I am running notebook2 from notebook1 using below command

```
dbutils.notebook.run("notebook2", 3600)
```

but this will run on cluster1, how can I make it run on cluster2 ?

Answer (score 3):

After digging through `dbutils.py`, I found a hidden argument to `dbutils.notebook.run()` called `_NotebookHandler__databricks_internal_cluster_spec` that accepts a [cluster configuration JSON](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/clusters-manage.html#view-a-cluster-configuration-as-a-json-file).

If you want to run "notebook2" on a cluster you've already created, you'll simply pass the JSON for that cluster.  If you want Databricks to create a *new* cluster for you, just define the cluster's resources under the key "new_cluster".  For example:

```py
cluster_config = '''
{
  "new_cluster": {
      "spark_version": "9.1.x-cpu-ml-scala2.12",
      "spark_conf": {
          "spark.databricks.delta.preview.enabled": "true"
      },
      ...
      "enable_elastic_disk": true,
      "num_workers": 4
  }
}
'''

dbutils.notebook.run('notebook2', 36000, _NotebookHandler__databricks_internal_cluster_spec=cluster_config)
```

I am only able to test this on Azure Databricks, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record. If you want to run the notebook job with a specified cluster, all you need to do is to find out the cluster id of your desired cluster and run as follows:

```
cluster_config = '''
{
  "existing_cluster_id": "****-032***82-bs34ww4f"
}
'''

dbutils.notebook.run('test_run_notebook', 36000, _NotebookHandler__databricks_internal_cluster_spec=cluster_config)
```

You can find the clusterId from the sideBar -> Compute -> select your cluster -> Press the "Automatically added tags"